# How to detect data on a specific port?

Tags: networking, kubuntu

I am writing an app for my phone which streams data to a specific port, but I am having problems and looking for a way to listen to a port on my Kubuntu 11.10 machine for incoming traffic.  Does anyone know a program which will show me if there is any data coming in on a specific port and how much?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution can be to use `netcat`:

```
nc -l port-number
```

`-l` for listening. May need admin privileges for listening on a port number lesser than 1024. Received data will be sent on stdout, so you may need redirection or piping to another command to use the data.

Also, the command should be active *before* some remote program connect to the port, otherwise the sending program will fail.

For more information, see netcat man page.

Comment: As an alternative you can install and use WireShark.  This will help highlight any header information that may be missed or not displayed using NetCat.

Answer (score 1):

[Ettercap](http://ettercap.sourceforge.net/) will do that for you and plus.

Install it with

> sudo apt-get install ettercap

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might want to run a capture script under `xinetd`.  This can also log the connections coming in at start and/or end of the connection.

Your capture script can do whatever you want it to do.  It can parse the data if you need or just count the size of the data transmitted.